# Erro na conexão com pdo_mysql ao utilizar docker com apache e mysql

Tags: php, pdo, apache, zend, docker

Estou utilizando docker com apache 5.6 + mysql:

[MySQL Oficial](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
[Docker PHP Oficial](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/)
[PHP - Versão 5.6](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/b66c0fa0286d0abbb8a36653e26e6992bb71b858/5.6/apache/Dockerfile)

Primeiro mandei rodar a imagem do mysql, depois executei a seguinte linha de comando para rodar a imagem do apache, linkando as duas:

> docker run -d -p 80:80 --expose 9000 -v ${PWD}/myproject:/var/www/html --link mydb:mysql --name mysystem myserver/my-build-apache

Até aí tudo bem, eu consigo fazer conexão usando o `mysqli_*`.

Entretanto, o sistema utiliza o recurso em PDO_Mysql, usando um arquivo de configuração: application.ini, ele seta a seguinte informação:

> resources.db.adapter = "PDO_Mysql"

Este arquivo é carregando em um sistema feito em Zend Framework 1.12.20

Ocorre que estou tendo o seguinte erro para carregar o socket do PDO:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)' in /var/www/html/webapp/pro/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php on line 336
>
> ( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /var/www/html/webapp/pro/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 129

Este é o [php.ini](https://gist.github.com/ivanferrer/6e4c69f2411d49436d04a8f33471e0e9)